# Validation firing for both controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

I currently have two partial views on a single page, added with:

```
@Html.Action("_LogonBox","Account")
@Html.Action("_TrackingBox","Tracking")
```

each has its own form and model...

but if I enter values into the _logonbox view and submit it it causes the validation to fire on the TrackingBox and because the values in tracking box are empty it highlights the textboxes as errors.

How do I sort this out, in webforms it was simply validationGroups?

**EDIT**

here is the markup:

**LogOn View**

```
  @model Models.LogonModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "account", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "Login" }))
    {
    <div class="boxwrapper">
        <div class="loginbox">
            <a href="#" style="float: right; color: #fff; font-size: 95%%; padding: 5px 10px;">Forgotten
                Password?</a>
            <h3>
                My Account</h3>
            <div class="content">
                <fieldset class="logincontrols">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="loginlabel">
                                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                            </td>
                            <td class="logintextbox">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { ValidationGroup = "Account" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="loginlabel">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                            </td>
                            <td class="logintextbox">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { ValidationGroup = "Account" })&nbsp;
                                <input type="image" value="Sign In" src="/Content/Images/buttons/signin.png" style="vertical-align: bottom;" ValidationGroup="Account" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>}
```

**Tracking View**

```
@model .Models.TrackingModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Tracking", new { Id = "Tracking" }))
{
<div class="boxwrapper">
    <div class="bluebox">
        <fieldset class="logincontrols">
        <h3>
            Shipment Tracking</h3>
        <div class="content">
            <p style="text-align: left;">
                &nbsp; &nbsp;Please enter your reference number:</p>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrackingNumber)
            <br />
            <p style="text-align: right; margin-top: 10px;">
                <input type="image" value="Track Shipment" src="/Content/Images/buttons/trackingbutton.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Further EDIT**
*added controllers as requested*

```
     public class TrackingController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Tracking/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(TrackingModel model)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public PartialViewResult _TrackingBox(TrackingModel model)
            {
                return PartialView(model);
            }

            public PartialViewResult _TrackingBox()
            {
                return PartialView();
            }
        }


public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        public PartialViewResult _Logonbox()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult _Logonbox(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //do something here
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return PartialView(model);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you also please add the controller code for the child actions, and for the HttpPosts of each form?

Comment: Have you tried changing `@Html.Action()` to `@Html.RenderAction()`?

Comment: @eth0 that results in the same issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this, but if someone can comment on WHY this fixes it that would be great.

I changed the `@Html.Action("_partialViewName")` to `@Html.Partial("_partialViewName")`, and this caused the same problems.

To fix this I had to include a new model object as below.

```
@Html.Partial("_LogonBox", new TGEFreight.UI.Web.Models.LogOnModel())
@Html.Partial("_TrackingBox", new TGEFreight.UI.Web.Models.TrackingModel())
```

As to why this works I dont know, this is probably due to my infancy with MVC, but this is the answer anyway.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: maybe because it was the same object triggering the validation in both events. And when you put your fix, you actually created 2 seperate objects

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that both of these field sets are wrapped in the same `<form>`. You can get around this by having a separate `<form>` for each partial / child action.

Unlike webforms, MVC lets you take full advantage of HTML, meaning you can have more than 1 form on a page. In webforms, everything needed to be on 1 page so that viewstate could be persisted for the entire page during each postback.

If you are using jquery unobtrusive validation, validations only fire for the form that was submitted.

**Edit**

Sorry, I re-read your question and you say each of these has its own form. Can you show more of the razor markup? What does your submit button look like? Are there any jquery or javascript behaviors attached to the forms? Is validation firing on the client or the server?

**Update**

Have you tried using @Html.Partial instead of @Html.Action? Html.Action results in a new HTTP request to the child action method. What view does your login action on your account controller return? It could be that the login POST is calling the tracking action as a POST, and causing validation to fire on it.

Comment: Also its sevrer side validation at the moment on the model

Comment: Hi, they are calling their own Actions, If I use Partial I cant define the Action for them to use.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @olivehour you should try using @Html.Partial instead of @Html.Action.  Now when you say that if you use Partial that you can't define the action for them to use, what exactly do you mean.   You should be able to define an HttpGet and HttpPost action without a problem for each of the partials, so for instance as an example you should be able to easily do the following:

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
 {
      ...
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Login()
      {
           return PartialView();
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
      {
          ... Validate Model & additional logic
          // return some redirect action
      }
 }
```

I noticed that in your post you are simply returning the PartialView again, was that just pseudo code?  If not, at least for the login partial, I would assume that if someone logs in that the post action would redirect them to another page.  In either case you would display the partial view by using @Html.Partial or @{Html.RenderPartial(...);} in your calling view.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Using the @Html.Action I can specify which partial to use, and also the controller to use.
The form within _LoginBox.cshtml posts back to the login page, this is where the logic would be to redirect to another url. As currently I havent actually done ANY code for logging in.
Using either Action OR partial gives me the same result... the validation fires for all the controls on the page, even though they are in DIFFERENT forms.